# Why I send a mail with PHP, but receiver get a mail with attachment named "mail.html"?

Tags: php, sendmail

```
$mailto = 'example@mail.com';
$subject = 'foo';
$message = 'bar';
mail($mailto, $subject, $message);
```

I open with the mail with OUTLOOK 2010, it display normally. But the mail has an attachment named "mail.html" that display "bar" when I open it in foxmail.

What is difference between these mail client? So this problem isn't seem a programming problem.

Comment: What is the `mailto()` function? is that something you've made or from a library of some sort?

Comment: @JamieTaylor it is my typo. I use PHP raw function mail()

Comment: This will be a settings issue in foxmail.  I don't use it myself so cannot help.  mail used in the way you do will send plain text.   Does foxmail open other emails correctly?  try sending a mail mail($mailto, $subject, $message,$htmlmessage); with "<HTML>foobar</HTML>" as $htmlmessage and see what happens.

Answer (score 2):

Did you use any headers?

```
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

// Mail it
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

Don't use foxmail so no clue if it works...but if you didn't send headers it's worth a try.